# How can I identify if my 'Cinelli' frame is real & what model it is?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage

I bought a road bike off ebay. Which is supposedly a Cinelli from the early 90s / late 80s. How can I identify the model?

Comment: Pictures might help. Also, look for a serial number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no decals or identifying markings, call Cinelli with the serial number which will be stamped into the bottom bracket shell. Otherwise, with no pics and no description, telepathy is the next best option. I don't posses that skill.

Comment: I didn't ask you to identify it, rather how can I identify it. cheers, I will try calling them.

Comment: @AndrewWelch so what was it?